# Is it allowed to statically link to a library licensed under Eclipse Public License 2.0 without publishing the source code of linked software?

Tags: licensing, license-recommendation, derivative-works

Let's say I've developed a library and licensed it under EPL 2.0.

If somebody statically links his/her software to my library, is that software considered a derivative/modified work?

Does s/he has to publish his/her source code?

Note: I want to allow the library users to statically or dynamically link their software without publishing their source code. If they modify my library, they must publish the modifications just to it and not the source code of their software.

Note 2: Unlike LGPL licenses, I don't want them to distribute their object files.